# Want to have a select list for a form pull from a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to pre-populate a drop down list in a Google Form from a list generated by a range in a Google Sheet. I can pull the list into an array, but can't seem to create the choice in the form.

```
  //Define sheet location (where vendor list range lives) and form location
  var se = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_ID_that_works");
  var vendorList = se.getSheetByName("vendorList");
  var vendorPullIn = sub.getRange("vendorListRange");
  var form = FormApp.openById('form_ID_that_works');
  var item = form.addListItem();
  item.setTitle('Select Vendor')
  var choiceList = vendorPullIn.getValues();
  item.setChoiceValues(choiceList);
```

Answer (score 0):

choices need to be in a single array...
[image]

.getValues() returns a 2d array...

[image]

one way to flatten values out...

```
  var choiceList = [];
    var values = vendorPullIn.getValues();
    for ( var row in values )
      for ( var col in values[row] ) 
        if ( values[row][col] ) 
          choiceList.push( values[row][col] );
```